# Why incorrect "pageCount" returned using Google Books API?

Tags: google-api, google-data-api, google-books

When I am calling "books.volumes.get" API, I am getting a "pageCount" which is different than calling "books.volumes.list" API for the exact same book.

Taking for example "Cryptography decrypted" book title, using the Google API Explorer I will get the following values for "pageCount":

- [books.volumes.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/books/v1/books.volumes.get?volumeId=wNFQAAAAMAAJ&_h=7&) : "pageCount"=392
- [books.volumes.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/books/v1/books.volumes.list?q=isbn%253A%209780201616477&_h=10&) : "pageCount" = 352

Pay attention that the volume ID is exactly the same in both query results. ("id"=wNFQAAAAMAAJ)

Any suggestion for this strange behavior? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Compare responses - they are different.

Publisher for first is "Addison-Wesley" and "Addison-Wesley Professional" for second.

It is total mess. According to book's [page](http://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Cryptography_decrypted.html?hl=&id=wNFQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) In first request is correct publisher but page count is wrong..

To my mind is better idea to send two letter with description of this situation. One to owner of API second to Addison-Wesley (request explanation about Professional). Not sure that your receive answer from second.. whatever..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree it's a total mess! Currently I am interested in solving only the "pageCount" issue although other fields are not consistent as well. The problem of "pageCount" is actually related not only to this specific book, but to ANY book I ever tested. For every tested book each of the above methods will return different value for "pageCount"!
I would love to give you the bounty but the answer I am looking for should provide an official reference to this issue by Google Books API team and its current resolution.